# Post variable not being caught in php sent from dynamically generated html

Tags: php, variables, post, href

Im having a really simple issue but iv looked around and cant debug it for some reason, can someone point me in the right direction??

I have a php script which dynamically generates a link

```
 <?php
  $id = 1;

  echo "<a href='http://www.example.com/page.php?id='$id'>click link</a>"

 ?>
```

On example.php I have...

```
 $userId = $_POST['id'];

 then I insert $userId query...
 ?>
```

For some reason the Post vairable is not being cause by the example.php script I can see it in the URL at the top of the page but they wont make sweet passionate php love. Any thoughts? I will mention I am doing this from within an IFRAME however I tried it simply and got the same result :(

Comment: Is it `example.php` or `page.php`?

Comment: sorry my bad http://www.example.com/page.php and yes it has an opening <?php tag lol

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean, on `page.php` you have...

If that is the case, you are sending the `id` parameter in a GET, not a POST.  To access it in your other page you need to use:

```
$userId = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: that's not the only problem: just try to run his code and see what echoes

Answer (score 0):

your variable is in `$userId = $_GET['id'];`.
another problem is a mess with ' symbols: should be

```
echo "<a href='http://www.example.com/page.php?id=$id'>click link</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you ar sending data via GET NOT POST

access it via $_GET['id'];